# End of line in shell variables

Tags: string, shell, sed

So I have `testfile` which contains

```
Line one
Another line
and this is the third line
```

My script reads this file, does some stuff and I end up with a variable that should contain it. Kind of doing

```
filevar=$(cat testfile)
```

(the important thing here is that I cannot access the file directly).

I'll be using the contents of that variable to generate an HTML code and one things I have to do is to add `<br>` to the end of each line. The problem is, there doesnt seem to any EOLs in my var:

```
echo $filevar
Line one Another line and this is the third line
```

How do I read the file properly to keep the EOLs? Once I have that I can simply `sed s/$/<br>/g`, but till then...

thanks!

Comment: did you accept the answer and then cancel? didn't that work for you?

Comment: @marcelog yep. Sorry for that. Your answer did actually work, but I was just curious to see if there were other alternatives and decided to leave it open a while more :) I'll check it back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `echo $filevar` do `echo "$filevar"` (note the double quotes).  This will send a single argument to echo and then you can pipe this to sed.

With sed, this will be treated as 3 lines, so you do not need the g option.  This works with me (bash and cygwin):

```
echo "$filevar" | sed 's/$/<br>/'
```

Comment: All the others are valid options, but I'm marking this as it was the one I used. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

how about changing IFS?

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=""
filevar=$(cat test)
echo $filevar
```

this will output:

```
Line one
Another line
and this is the third line
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why do you need to read the file into the variable. Why don't you simply do this:

```
sed 's|$|<br/>|' testfile
```

**UPDATE:**

If you really want to get the EOL back in your variable. Try this (notice the quotes):

```
echo "$filevar"
```

But I still can't understand, **why you can `cat` the file but not access the file**

As a solution, I would suggest the following script:

```
while read LINE
do
  echo ${LINE} '<br />'   # Implement your core logic here.
done < testfile
```

Comment: Man.. could you stick to the topic? It is not because you can't understand that it shouldn't be. You could have copied you answer from my question if this was the case. I this case it _has_ to be done this way. Vote down for unhelpfulness.

Comment: @filippo: May I note that I had a similar answer in mind, because from 'cannot access the file directly', it wasn't so obviously clear, what was meant.

Comment: @ssapkota Good stuff, thanks for the update! The ``cat`` thing is just an example. This is actually for a function in a library which will be used in many scripts. I gave ``$(cat testfile)`` because is generally how the variable being filled. From the pov where this code is going, the ``$filevar`` is already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `IFS` variable to contain just a newline, and then reference the `filevar` variable *without* quotes.

```
$ filevar='Line one
Another line
and this is the third line'

$ for word in $filevar; do echo "$word<br>"; done
Line<br>
one<br>
Another<br>
line<br>
and<br>
this<br>
is<br>
the<br>
third<br>
line<br>

$ for word in "$filevar"; do echo "$word<br>"; done
Line one
Another line
and this is the third line<br>

$ (IFS=$'\n'; for word in $filevar; do echo "$word<br>"; done)
Line one<br>
Another line<br>
and this is the third line<br>
```